# Inheritance in SWIG Directors

Tags: c++, swig

When I create a SWIG Director for a class A inheriting from class B it fails when the C++ library tries to call methods of class B.

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Swig::DirectorMethodException: SWIG director method error. Error detected when calling 'B.MethodB'
```

Is there any limitation on SWIG Directors support for classes with multiple levels of inheritance?

UPDATE: The actual code below

```
class RefCountInterface {
 public:
  virtual int AddRef() = 0;
  virtual int Release() = 0;
 protected:
  virtual ~RefCountInterface() {}
};

class SessionObserver : public RefCountInterface {
 public:
  virtual void OnSuccess() = 0;
  virtual void OnFailure() = 0;

 protected:
  ~SessionObserver() {}
};

void CreateOffer(SessionObserver* observer); // This ends up calling observer->Release and that raises the exception

%module(directors="1") module
%feature("director") SessionObserver;
```

Python code:

```
class MySessionObserver(module.SessionObserver):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        module.SessionObserver.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.count = 1

    def AddRef(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count

    def Release(self):
        self.count -= 1
        return self.count

    def OnSuccess(self, desc):
        print "OnSuccess"

    def OnFailure(self, err):
        print "OnFailure"
```

Comment: Can we see your code for class A, class B, and your director code?

Comment: Test updated, let me know if there is something else needed

Comment: Why are your destructors protected?

Comment: Also, do you have directors turned on? Finally, do you ever create a concrete derived class from `SessionObserver` in your client code? Do all this, and then check back please. Also amend your post.

Comment: The C++ code is from a third party library, I'm not sure why they use protected destructors.

Comment: I have directors turned on, rest of them work but not this one, I guess it is because the multiple levels of inheritance.    I create a concrete class, I included it in the amended post.    Thank you ver much @AndyG

Comment: Does your declaration of %module(directors="1") come before inclusion of SessionObserver's header file?

Comment: Yes, %module(directors="1")  is the first line of the .i file.   Does it work for you with multiple levels of inheritance?

Comment: I don't have SWIG on the machine I'm currently running :(. I'm not sure what the problem is, maybe it's just not supported yet in SWIG? Can you show a more complete .i file? I want to make sure you use both #include and %include for your header. Sadly I'm no SWIG expert, but it appears I'm all you have :)

Comment: Yep, I have #include and %include.   As I said it works fine for the other directors I have in the application, it is only this one that fails :(.  Thx again

Comment: All I can think of is to derive into a concrete class in C++, and then use your director on that concrete class and inherit from it instead. Best of luck!